# How To Enlarge Chrome 37.0.xxx Title Bar

Tags: google-chrome, titlebar

My Chrome updated itself since last last week, seems the font blurry issue was fixed, however the title bar becomes smaller, I still prefer the previous size of the title bar, look the below comparison between latest Firefox and Chrome 37.x (you might see the size below still okay, but from my laptop screen, the size might be only around 70% of the capture, don't why the captured image was enlarged here after uploaded.)

[image]

**Environment**:

OS: Windows 8.1

Screen: 1920x1080 HDPI.

Anybody knows how to enlarge the size of title bar?

Thanks.

Comment: E,n.l-a.r,g.e your title bar with these 10 quick tips. #3 will make you sneeze.

Comment: @bzlm I don't get your mean?